# ¿Cómo depurar una aplicación en nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, depuración

Estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar aplicaciones web con el *stack* `MEAN` y me surgió una duda; ¿cómo *debuguear* una aplicación en Node.js?

Teniendo en cuenta que vengo del desarrollo de aplicaciones web en Java, donde las herramientas de *debug* de *Eclipse* son muy buenas.

Además, para proyectos en JavaScript, no utilizo ningún IDE en particular, solo un editor de texto como SublimeText.

Comment: He votado para cerrar. La pregunta me parece interesante y útil, pero así formulada es demasiado amplia. Una (mala) respuesta válida podría ser "hacer _console.log()_" o usar las "developer tools del navegador o similar. Creo que la pregunta mejoraría si preguntases por IDEs específicos, diferenciases depurar en cliente o servidor para una app web, si hay herramientas específicas para la _MEAN Machine_, etc. La calidad de las respuesta mejoraría. Como es útil te dejo el +1, y espero que se obtengan respuesta de calidad, porque a mi también me interesa.

Comment: Esta pregunta va a ser probablemente cerrada =( aunque me parece también interesante por eso +1 para las respuestas (bueno, menos para mí ya que no puedo =( ).

Comment: @DiegoAlonso agradezco tu comentario, como mejorarias la pregunta para que no sea cerrada ? Me di cuenta que es amplia la pregunta, pero tampoco hay muchas maneras de preguntar, ya muchas veces no se utiliza IDEs para JS, Saludos

Comment: Yo intentaría dar un poco de contexto, tipo qué herramientas ya usas y qué técnicas de debug conoces. Pero ahora hay que cuidar que una edición no anule alguna respuesta ya dada...

Comment: Hola, bueno en mi respuesta he añadido más detalles de Visual Studio Code, que es un editor ligero tipo Sublime Text pero con herramientas de depuración.

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a editar el spanglish, en Latinoamérica la mezcla entre español e inglés no solo es habitual sino que ya es parte de nuestra cultura.

Comment: @Santi92, voy a retirar el voto, porque los _edits_ me parecen buenos. Yo también uso _Sublime_ y mucho _console.log()_ porque no tengo/conozco otra cosa. Creo que básicamente hay a) herramientas para depurar (IDEs como InteliJ, o módulos como el node-inspector? y b) técnicas para depurar (herramientas de desarrollador del navegador y logs). La opción B ya la conocíamos, y sobre la opción A la mayoría de respuestas dadas invitan más a cambiarte de editor que a usar un complemente de _Sublime_ (pero la pregunta tampoco dice que quieras quedarte con _Sublime_ necesariamente...)

Comment: @DiegoAlonso gracias Diego, en si no me convence la idea de cambiar de ide, me voy a inclinar por usar el modulo node-inspector . nuevamente gracias

Comment: relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164916/funcionalidades-que-posee-la-funci%c3%b3n-console

Answer (score 11):

Una cosa es debugguear/depurar y otra cosa muy diferente son las pruebas unitarias.

[**Mocha**](http://mochajs.org/) es un framework para hacer pruebas unitarias.

Herramientas para nodeJS hay muchas, algunas simples IDE,  otras muy buenas herramientas pero de consola.

Si no quieres IDEs pero si manejar un editor sencillo tipo *Sublime* text entonces con  [**Visual Studio Code**](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/code-vs.aspx) puedes hacer debugging de NodeJS , es súper ligero y corre en todas las plataformas.Allí tienes ayudas gráficas de depuración e Intellisense.

Más info: [Debugging a Node.js with Visual Studio Code](https://youtu.be/67Q-s07Z_EQ)

Pero si quieres tener una herramienta profesional (gratuita) para desarrollar con NodeJS y hacer debugging REAL - no solo pruebas unitarias -  definitivamente debes utilizar [Visual Studio](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=626924&clcid=0x409) con las [Herramientas de NodeJS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx).

He creado un **video** al respecto y lo he colgado en Channel 9

### [**Visual Studio 2015 | #1 NodeJS Tools**](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Ninja-Tips/30-Ninja-Tips-Visual-Studio-2015-1-NodeJS-Tools)

Considero que allí encontrarás todo lo que deseas.

Comment: Lo que entiendo de las reglas en `/help/promotion`, lo importante es declarar "el enlace es para un site/contenido creado por mi" y que sea relevante para la respuesta. Tu texto dice eso claramente, que es un video y que es tuyo. También, como norma general para ese tipo de situación, la idea es "si quitamos tu enlace, la respuesta se mantiene por si misma?". Sí la respuesta es sí, entonces no hay problema.

Answer (score 1):

Uso sublimetext para desarrollar, el cual no me ofrece herramientas de depuración, pero googleando un poco conseguí el modulo [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector). También cuando me encuentro atascado en algo utilizo los `console.log` a lo largo del código para tratar de conseguir el error.

Sin embargo te recomiendo usar algún framework o usar estándares para reducir el mínimo posible la cantidad de tiempo invertido en depuración.

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254025/node-js-unit-testing) que está en inglés (en la cual estoy de acuerdo por conocer el tema), la alternativa que tienes es usar [Mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/expresso), o en su defecto [Expresso](https://github.com/visionmedia/expresso), este último sería el antecesor del primero y ambos son frameworks de pruebas unitarias pero sirven para depurar de aplicaciones en Javascript.

Con respecto a cómo usarlo, en las páginas de los mismos hay tutoriales que son de gran ayuda, y la verdad por mi experiencia me quedo con estos aunque yo he trabajo más con mocha y me ha resultado.

Adicionalmente usar `console.log` puede ser útil para cosas pequeñas, para pruebas mas grandes y profundas los mencionados arriba.

Comment: *Mocha* es sucesor de *Expresso*, y no al revés, como das a entender en tu respuesta.  Igualmente, ambos son frameworks para realizar *pruebas automatizadas*, no para depurar el código.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal, yo solía usar Expresso que menciona Wilfredo, pero la última vez recuerdo que ya no funcionaba, de hecho ese proyecto se dejó hace tiempo (último commit 30 Oct 2012), en la actualidad lo recomendable es usar Chrome con [Google Chrome Developer Tools for Java](https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/)

Pero hay un inconveniente : **El proyecto ha sido descontinuado.**

La respuesta más sensata podría ser:  usar el método `console.log()`

Comment: Yo creo que al final todo lleva a mocha, jajajajajaja

Comment: cambiaria tu respuesta a solo `console` este tiene otras funcionalidades como `console.trace ` `console.timeStart` `console.table` entre otros mira esta pregunta aunque la hice algun tiempo ahora veo que es como redundante [Funcionalidades que posee la función console](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/164937/28035)

Answer (score 1):

## Debuguear aplicaciones con node.js

Pasaron 5 años de la pregunta y de la respuesta. Hoy hay otras alternativas.

**Se puede debuguear una aplicación node.js con varios entornos.** Por ejemplo **Visual Studio Code** permite hacer ejecución paso a paso, poner puntos de interrupción (fijos y condicionales) y mirar y cambiar el contenido de las variables. Además permite debuguear aplicaciones escritas tanto en *Javascript* como en *Typescript*

### Respuesta anterior

Uso mucho node.js y varias cosas te puedo decir:

1. `console.log` y todo el output directo es muy útil
2. Utilizar casos de prueba es ideal (pero muy dificultoso cuando no lo arrancaste de entrada). Uso [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/) y me da excelentes resultados.

**Consejo**. Para cosas complejas `console.log` puede generar una salida muy grande, a veces lo que yo hago es tener una variable booleana `empezar_a_loguear` para empezar a ver a partir de detectar cierta condición:

```
empezar_a_loguear = detecto_el_problema();
//...
if(empezar_a_loguear){
    console.log(las_variables_sensibles);
}
```