# Como puedo hacer Debugger en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Leyendo la pregunta [como mostrar datos en un JSON](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164682/mostrar-datos-de-mi-json), agregue un comentario acerca de como mostrarlo usando el `console.table`, Que otras funcionalidades tiene el console.

Comment: No se si están todas las opciones pero una buena documentación es la de MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El comando **`console`** puede servirte para muchas cosas, te dejare las mas comunes:

1. Para la Visualización de código

```js
console.info("info");
console.warn("Warning");
console.debug("debug"); //funcion bloqueada en el snippet
console.error("error");
const miObjeto= {
  usuario : "jacknavarow",
  comunidad : ["es.stackoverflow", "stackoverflow", "ubuntu ask"]
}
console.dir(miObjeto);
console.table(miObjeto.comunidad)
```

2. Verificar si funciones devuelven un valor esperado

```js
function validaPar(numero){
  return true
}
let numeroImpar = 1

console.assert(validaPar(numeroImpar) == false, `validaPar invalido numero ingresado ${numeroImpar}` )
```

3. Formas de ver el rendimiento de funciones/metodos

```js
console.time()
setTimeout(() =>{ 
  //mostrara el resultado que se demoro desde el time hasta el timeEnd
  console.timeEnd()
}, 1000);
```

4. Verificar las iteraciones de un proceso ciclico:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.count();
}
```

5. Agrupar tu informacion y/o hacer traza

```js
function a(){
  
  console.group("a");
  console.trace();
  console.log("ejecutando a");
  console.groupEnd();
}
function b(){
  console.group("b");
  console.trace();
  console.log("ejecutando b");
  console.groupEnd();
}
a()
b()
```

> Por supuesto puedes mezclar todas las funciones para tu uso en
>   particular. si quieres saber que metodos tiene **`console`** abre el
>   navegador y escribe console en tu consola de errores

Si quieres ver mas puedes ir a la web de [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console)