# Cómo puedo reducir array

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo este `array`, deseo reducirlo y obtener un nuevo `array` que contenga solo el campo `c_docu`:

```
var array = [
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102556", "l_agen": "MONTALVO MEZA NORMA"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102558", "l_agen": "SOTO CUEVA OSCAR  OBID"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102564", "l_agen": "QUISPE RAMOS MARGARITA"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102563", "l_agen": "SALVADOR ORIHUELA  CASILDA M."},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102875", "l_agen": "TAYPE QUISPE ISENIA"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102880", "l_agen": "DE LA CRUZ TAIPE JULIA"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102626", "l_agen": "GOBIERNO REGIONAL JUNIN"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102697", "l_agen": "TAYPE DE LA CRUZ MAGNO"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102512", "l_agen": "PEREZ QUISPE, ESTANES VICTOR"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0100088", "l_agen": "ALIAGA LAURA JAVIER"}
]
```

este el resultado que deseo obtener

```
var array2 = [
    "0102556",
    "0102564",
    "0102563",
    "0102875",
    "0102880",
    "0102626",
    "0102697",
    "0102512",
    "0100088"
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para realizar lo que necesitas, el método **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)** te viene perfecto

```js
const array = [
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102556", "l_agen": "MONTALVO MEZA NORMA"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102558", "l_agen": "SOTO CUEVA OSCAR  OBID"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102564", "l_agen": "QUISPE RAMOS MARGARITA"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102563", "l_agen": "SALVADOR ORIHUELA  CASILDA M."},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102875", "l_agen": "TAYPE QUISPE ISENIA"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102880", "l_agen": "DE LA CRUZ TAIPE JULIA"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102626", "l_agen": "GOBIERNO REGIONAL JUNIN"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102697", "l_agen": "TAYPE DE LA CRUZ MAGNO"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0102512", "l_agen": "PEREZ QUISPE, ESTANES VICTOR"},
    {"c_docu": "00", "n_docu": "0100088", "l_agen": "ALIAGA LAURA JAVIER"}
]

const data = array.map(x => ({ n_docu: x.n_docu }))

console.log(data)
```

Resumiendo, lo que hace el método `map` es extraer la información que necesitas y crear un nuevo `array` sólo con los valores deseados.

Comment: muchas gracias, exactamente lo que deseaba!!

Comment: @FredyAlarconOrdoñez si te sirvió la respuesta, favor marcala para futuros OP con las mismas inquietudes! :D

Comment: sabias que podias usar [console.table(Data)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/164937/28035)

Comment: :O edite el codigo pero no me mostro nada, lo estare implementando mal me imagino

Comment: es el stacksnippet, solo queria mostrarte que el console es mas pontente de lo que crees, ejecutalo en el navegador para que lo veas!

Comment: Siempre sospeche que console era mas que un log, jejejee... excelente dato!

Answer (score 6):

Lo que necesitas es reducir objetos dentro de un array en realidad, y como ha dicho @Paulo `.map` es exactamente lo que necesitas, solo agregaría que para reducir los objetos individuales, la asignación por destructuring lo haría mas corto aún:

```js
var array = [{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0102556","l_agen":"MONTALVO MEZA NORMA"},{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0102558","l_agen":"SOTO CUEVA OSCAR  OBID"},{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0102564","l_agen":"QUISPE RAMOS MARGARITA"},{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0102563","l_agen":"SALVADOR ORIHUELA  CASILDA M."},{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0102875","l_agen":"TAYPE QUISPE ISENIA"},{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0102880","l_agen":"DE LA CRUZ TAIPE JULIA"},{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0102626","l_agen":"GOBIERNO REGIONAL JUNIN"},{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0102697","l_agen":"TAYPE DE LA CRUZ MAGNO"},{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0102512","l_agen":"PEREZ QUISPE, ESTANES VICTOR"},{"c_docu":"00","n_docu":"0100088","l_agen":"ALIAGA LAURA JAVIER"}];

const res = array.map(({n_docu})=>n_docu);

console.log(res);
```